# PROBLEMA CON actionProductUpdate EN PRESTASHOP

Tags: prestashop1.7

Creé un modulo e hice el registro del hook actionProductUpdate, pero no funciona, ya he probado con actionProductAdd, actionProductSave, actionObjectProductUpdateAfter, actionProductAttributeUpdate. Pero sin existo. Alguien que ya tuvo ese mismo problema?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: He creado un modulo, y quiero sobrescribir el hook actionProductUpdate, te envío una captura https://contalapp.com/hook.png